# Bootstrap clearer height differs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm usuably using bootstrap to build up my responsive websites and I'm using the clearer-class to enable a correct clearing on mobile devices. As it can be seen in the fiddle below, the clearer-height differs in my last row - because the row is not completely filled.

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
           <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>           
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>           
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
           <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
           <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>           
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>           
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
           <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div> 
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
           <div class="clearfix visible-xs">&nbsp;</div>           
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" />
                      <div class="caption">Test</div>
               </div>               
           </div>
           <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

So the question is:

Why has the last clearfix a height of 190px,
while all other clearfixes have a height of 210px?

Comment: Why are you even using clearfix? You have no reason to.

Comment: Hi Joe, 
imagine this: You're clicking one of the boxes and a JS loads external content below the box you've clicked. To make sure the position of the external content is always correct (responsive) I'm using another JS to determine which clearfix is the next (selected by visibility), so that I can paste my external content after that one. Because of that, I need these clearfixes :-)

Comment: Your clearfixes don't have a height of 190px or 210px.